# Equivalent of glOrtho in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In OpenGL I can do this:

```
glOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, -1, 1)
```

to establish a coordinate system where x ranges from -10 to 10 and y ranges from -10 to 10.

Is there a way to change the coordinate system of a canvas in WPF?

Comment: How are you going to position elements in that Canvas? The `Top`, `Left`. `Right` and `Bottom` properties would loose their meaning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created an extension method on Canvas that allows you to set a Cartesian coordinate system. An example invocation is:

```
canvas.SetCoordinateSystem(-10, 10, -10, 10)
```

That will set the coordinate system of `canvas` so that x goes from -10 to 10 and y goes from -10 to 10.

Here's the extension method:

```
public static Canvas SetCoordinateSystem(this Canvas canvas, Double xMin, Double xMax, Double yMin, Double yMax)
{
    var width = xMax - xMin;
    var height = yMax - yMin;

    var translateX = -xMin;
    var translateY = height + yMin;

    var group = new TransformGroup();

    group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(translateX, -translateY));
    group.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(canvas.ActualWidth / width, canvas.ActualHeight / -height));

    canvas.RenderTransform = group;

    return canvas;
}
```

Here's a demo program which plots Sin(x) on a canvas along with the X and Y axes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CanvasScale
{
    public static class CanvasUtils
    {
        public static Canvas SetCoordinateSystem(this Canvas canvas, Double xMin, Double xMax, Double yMin, Double yMax)
        {
            var width = xMax - xMin;
            var height = yMax - yMin;

            var translateX = -xMin;
            var translateY = height + yMin;

            var group = new TransformGroup();

            group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(translateX, -translateY));
            group.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(canvas.ActualWidth / width, canvas.ActualHeight / -height));

            canvas.RenderTransform = group;

            return canvas;
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var canvas = new Canvas();

            Content = canvas;

            SizeChanged += (s, e) => canvas.SetCoordinateSystem(-10, 10, -10, 10);                

            canvas.Children.Add(new Line() { X1 = -10, Y1 = 0, X2 = 10, Y2 = 0, Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 0.2 });
            canvas.Children.Add(new Line() { X1 = 0, Y1 = -10, X2 = 0, Y2 = 10, Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 0.2 });

            var polyline = new Polyline()
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.BurlyWood,
                StrokeThickness = 0.1,
                Points = new PointCollection()
            };

            for (var x = -10.0; x <= 10.0; x += 0.1)
                polyline.Points.Add(new Point(x, Math.Sin(x)));

            canvas.Children.Add(polyline);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Note that canvas.ActualHeight can be (and is) zero right after InitializeComponent(), so `0 / x = 0` and you have set your ScaleTransform to {0;0}. And that can be confusing, becouse canvas visualy disappear... Solution: [force Measure && Arrange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695101/why-are-actualwidth-and-actualheight-0-0-in-this-case#answer-1695518)

Answer (score 1):

[`OrthographicCamera`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.orthographiccamera.aspx) provides an orthogonal projection instead of the more common perspective projection (`PerspectiveCamera`).

To establish the 'range' of coordinates that are visible from the camera you will probably have to fiddle with the `Width` and `Position` properties.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not also set the `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Right` or `Canvas.Bottom` properties, you could set the [LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) or [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) property of each child in the Canvas to an appropriate TransformGroup or [MatrixTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.aspx):

```
Rect viewport = new Rect(-10, -10, 20, 20);
double scaleX = ActualWidth / viewport.Width;
double scaleY = ActualHeight / viewport.Height;
RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(
    scaleX, 0d, 0d, scaleY, -viewport.X * scaleX, -viewport.Y * scaleY);
```

Comment: Hi Clemens. I ended up doing something along these lines. I added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079610/equivalent-of-glortho-in-wpf/13093518#13093518).