# How do I draw with coordinates in [0;1] instead of pixels in WPF?

Tags: wpf

My coordinates are relative to the control size, in the 0 to 1 range. I currently draw on my control using manual scaling by `RenderSize`, which works fine, but is surely the wrong way.

How can I draw directly in 0-1 coordinates instead?

Comment: What control do you use for "drawing"? I mean, what surface are you drawing on?

Comment: @Matas A class derived from `UserControl`

Comment: and what kind of things are you drawing? Graphics? Or other controls?

Comment: @Matas I'm drawing a lot of graphics (lines, rectangles etc).

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254125/change-the-coordinate-system-of-a-canvas-in-wpf)

Comment: @Matas Thank you, I will check it!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Path` controls and scale their `Data` by applying an appropriate transform to the `Geometry.Transform` property, like in the trivial example shown below. This way you would scale the drawn shapes, but not their stroke thicknesses.

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.Resources>
            <ScaleTransform x:Key="transform"
                            ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=scaleSlider}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=scaleSlider}"/>
        </Canvas.Resources>

        <Path Stretch="None" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2">
            <Path.Data>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0.1,0.1,0.8,0.4"
                                   Transform="{StaticResource transform}"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <Path Stretch="None" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="0.6,0.5" RadiusX="0.3" RadiusY="0.3"
                                 Transform="{StaticResource transform}"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>

    <Slider x:Name="scaleSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="100" Minimum="100" Maximum="500"/>
</Grid>
```